# Pandas: multiple patterns in different rows

Tags: pandas, pattern-matching

I've pandas rows and trying to find efficient way to find if somewhere "first-match" is found in the row then check and alert if the second-match is anywhere in next lines. something like (a & b & c) but on different lines.

```
name  id    my-patterns
mori  01c   this-is zero match ..
dave  a1c   this-is first-match ..  
stev  b2c   this-is no match no ..
hola  c2c   this-is second-match .. 
many  more  this-is 3rd-match ..
```

I could probably achieve that by 2 iterations like below but this isn't good. If there are thousands of rows it would kill performance.

```
f = df[df['my-patterns'].str.contains("first-match")].index[0]
if f > 0:
   df = df[f+1:]
   df1['my-match'] =  df['my-patterns'].str.contains("second-match")
   if len(df1):
      do_process
```

Any better ways ? Is there something that can be done in one iteration like if first match found than change pattern to second-match and continue search, if that found then change 3rd match ?

Comment: Please add sample of your data and expected output

Comment: expected output could just be lines containing all matches. eg. 
dave  a1c   this-is first-match
hola  c2c   this-is second-match
many  more  this-is 3rd-match

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it makes sense to step aside from pandas in this task and really search for patterns one-by-one using lists.

Here's my attempt.

Creating a large mock dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import string

def get_random_string(length):
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    result_str = "".join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(length))
    return result_str

length = 100000
n_matches = 200

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "id": [get_random_string(3) for _ in range(length)],
    "my-patterns": [get_random_string(20) for _ in range(length)]
})

matches = np.random.choice(a=range(0, length), size=n_matches, replace=False)

for i, match_idx in enumerate(matches):
    df["my-patterns"].loc[match_idx] = "{}-match".format(i)
```

Searching for patterns one by one until the next one can't be found:

```
pattern_idx = 0

for i, value in enumerate(df["my-patterns"]):
    if target_patterns[pattern_idx] in value:
        pattern_idx += 1
        
        if pattern_idx == len(target_patterns):
            break

if pattern_idx == len(target_patterns):
    print("Found all")
elif pattern_idx == 0:
    print("Found none")
else:
    print("Last found pattern: '{}'".format(target_patterns[pattern_idx - 1]))
```

Output:

```
Last found pattern: '10-match'
CPU times: user 15 ms, sys: 3.2 ms, total: 18.2 ms
Wall time: 18.2 ms
```

If you need to do stuff after finding each pattern - you can add function calls after `pattern_idx += 1`

Comment: I liked the 1st form of enumerating matches as it might be lighter than 2nd which is enumerating df as it could be expensive. Also the pattern could even be regex so i'll try with str.contains instead of "{}-match".format(i) and compare the 2. Thanks for your help.